# pgadmin4 connect to postgres in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, pgadmin-4

I am not able to connect through pgAdmin4 to Google Cloud SQL. 
Following are the credentials I am providing and getting the error messege:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you configuring access for public IP connections?

Answer (score 4):

To connect with **Google Cloud SQL** using **pgadmin** client, you can use [cloud_sql_proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy#install)

These steps need to follow:

1. Establish connection to Postgres.
   `cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<connection string>=tcp:5433`

You will get connection string from GCP here
[image]

After executing cloud_sql_proxy, you will see something like this
[image]

2. Now create a new server connection using pgadmin client.

[image]

[image]

If you followed those steps properly it will connect and can use like local pgadmin.

Answer (score 3):

If you are configuring access for public IP connections, follow the next steps to connect with PgAdmin:

1) Create your PostgreSQL instance in Google Cloud Platform.

2) While creating the instance,

- In **Instance ID** tab, write a name for your instance
- In Default user password tab, write a password.
- Choose the region.
- Click on **configuration options**, go to **Connectivity**, enable Public IP, under **Authorized networks**, add **network** and their write the **IP address of your PC**. You can check the IP address in the [link](http://www.myipaddress.com/show-my-ip-address/) .
- Click on create.

Then in PgAdmin:

1) In Host name/address put Public IP address of the instance.

Comment: This is a good answer. One suggestion is to show how to use the Cloud SQL Proxy which improves security.

Answer (score 1):

Nibrass H has perfectly answered this question.
But I would like to add that if you have already created the Instance, then you can click on 'Edit Instance' and Add your IP in 'Connections'.

Adding some Images to help you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I received **Unable to connect to server: timeout expired** error, the following steps helped:

- Opened up GCP
- then into your db instance > connections
- Under Network you'll see **Add new network**
- Enter any name and enter your IP to allow local host connections. ( your ip can be found here at: https://whatismyipaddress.com/

For more info refer to this helpful [doc](https://cshiva.medium.com/connecting-to-gcps-cloud-sql-postgressql-from-pgadmin-3-simple-steps-2f4530488a4c).